# finding an integral .

Tags: calculus, integration

I can’t find the integral  $$\int x^2 \sqrt{2x-4}dx, $$ and am so confused between using the integration by parts or the integration by u substitution, if any one please can tell me which method to use .

Comment: You can definitely do parts once with the setup: $u = x^2$ and $dv = \sqrt{2x - 4} dx$. Afterwards you should be able to do the remaining integral by substitution.

Comment: well , thank you buddy , that helped me a lot .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, $\sqrt{2x-4}=u \implies \frac{2}{2\sqrt{2x-4}}\ dx=du$ or $dx=u\ du$, hence one should get $$\int x^2\sqrt{2x-4}\ dx$$ $$=\int \left(\frac{u^2+4}{2}\right)^2\ u(u\ du)$$
$$= \frac{1}{4}\int (u^6+8u^4+16u^2)\ du$$

I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Could someone please tell me the reason for what is wrong in the answer?

Comment: You're wasting your breath.  Some people just downvote here.  That's all.

Comment: Welcome to the club of the victims of very silent downvoters ! $+1$ because it is a good answer. Cheers :-)

Comment: thanks bro  , that definitely helped .

Answer (score 0):

Sub $x=y+2$ to get

$$\sqrt{2} \int dy \, (y+2)^2 \sqrt{y}  = \sqrt{2} \int dy \, \left (y^{5/2} + 4 y^{3/2} + 4 y^{1/2}\right )$$

which you should be able to do:

$$2 \sqrt{2} \left [\frac17 (x-2)^{7/2} + \frac45 (x-2)^{5/2} + \frac43 (x-2)^{3/2}\right ] + C$$